# How to calculate marginal distribution of conditional distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

So like let $Y | \mu  \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\mu $. $P(Y =y | \mu ) = \frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^y}{y!}$. Let $\mu \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta )$. I'm looking to find the marginal distribution of Y i.e. $P(Y = y)$

I don't have a textbook but found online that the equation is

$$P(Y = y) = \int_{x}^{y} P(Y = y | \mu )f(\mu )du$$

How do I find the limits for x and y ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement), $P(Y=y) = \int\limits_R P(Y=y|X=x)f_X(x)dx$, where $X$ is some continuous random variable and $R$ is the support of $X$. Letting $X$~$\mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta), R = (0,\infty).$ Thus the limits of your integration should be $0$ and $\infty$. Hope that helps.